# Double Linked List C#. How do I delete all the nodes in my double linked list

Tags: c#, linked-list, nodes

Im trying to delete all the nodes in my double linked list but am having trouble. my variable this.Start is null when debugging which causes my code not to work. I am unable to figure out a solution. Is there an alternate way to delete my nodes or fix my current code. Please help Thank you:D

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
    
    SeatManager _seatManager = new SeatManager();
    DoubleLinkedList seatList = new DoubleLinkedList();
    Seat _seat = new Seat();
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

   
    
    private void buttonCreateAndDisplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        
                Label labelSeat = new Label();
                
                        
                        labelSeat.Click+=new EventHandler(HandleLabelClick);
                        Seat seat = _seatManager.InsertOneSeat(y, x);
                        labelSeat.Tag=seat;
                        labelSeat.Text=seat.ComputeSeatLabel();
                        

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        

    }
    private void HandleLabelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string labelName = "";
        Label labelSeat = (Label)sender;
        Seat seat = (Seat)labelSeat.Tag;
        labelMessage.Text=labelSeat.Name;
        
            if (seat.BookStatus==false)
            {
                seat=_seatManager.FindOneSeatToBook(seat.Row, seat.Column);
            }
            else
            {
                seat=_seatManager.FindOneSeatToUnbook(seat.Row, seat.Column);
            }
            if (seat.BookStatus==false)
            {
                labelSeat.BackColor=Color.LightGray;
            }
            else
            {
                labelSeat.BackColor=Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
            }
        }
       
      
    }

   


    private void buttonReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        seatList.ClearNodes(maxRow,maxColumn);  
        seatList.deleteAllNodes();
        _resetbuttonclicked=true;
        panelSeats.Controls.Clear();
        buttonCreateAndDisplay_Click(sender, e);

    }
```

DoubleLinkedList

```
class DoubleLinkedList
    {
    public Node Start { get; set; }
    
    public DoubleLinkedList()
    {
        this.Start=null;
    }
    
    public void InsertAtEnd(Seat seatData)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node(seatData);
        if (this.Start==null)
        {
            this.Start=newNode;
            return;
        }
        Node p = this.Start;
        while (p.next!=null)
        {
            p=p.next;
            
        }
        p.next=newNode;
        newNode.prev=p;

    }

    
    public Seat SearchByRowAndColumn(int pRow, int pColumn)
    {
        Node p = this.Start;
        while (p!=null)
        {
            if ((p.seat.Column == pColumn) && (p.seat.Row == pRow))
            {   
                break;
            }
            p=p.next;
        }
        if (p==null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return p.seat;
        }
    }

    public Seat ClearNodes(int pRow,int pColumn)
    {
        Node p = this.Start;
        while (p != null)
        {
            p=p.prev;
            p.next=null;
        }
        return null;

    }

    public void deleteAllNodes()
    {
        Node seat = new Node();
        while (this.Start != null)
        {
           seat = this.Start;
           this.Start = this.Start.next;
           seat = null;
        }
        this.Start=null;
    }
```

SeatManager

```
 class SeatManager
        {
        DoubleLinkedList _seats;
        public SeatManager()
        {
            _seats= new DoubleLinkedList();
        }
        public Seat InsertOneSeat(int row, int column)
        {
            Seat newSeat = new Seat();
            newSeat.Row = row;
            newSeat.Column = column;
            newSeat.CanBook = true;
            newSeat.Bookedby = "";
            _seats.InsertAtEnd(newSeat);
            return newSeat;
        }
        
    public Seat FindOneSeatToBook(int row, int column)
    {
        Seat seat = _seats.SearchByRowAndColumn(row, column);
        seat.BookStatus=true;
        return seat;
    }
    public Seat FindOneSeatToUnbook(int row, int column)
    {
        Seat seat = _seats.SearchByRowAndColumn(row, column);
        seat.BookStatus = false;
        return seat;
    }
```

Comment: Please show your debugging code that calls `deleteAllNodes()` and, presumably, `InsertAtEnd()`.  `Start` will remain `null` until something changes it, which nothing here does.

Comment: Can you post a compilable console app that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Incidentally, because C# uses garbage collection, to delete all the nodes it suffices to set `this.Start = null`. (Unless something else is hanging on to a reference to Start or one of its nodes, but then you're going to be in trouble no matter what.)

Comment: Can you show us code which inserts data into linked list. BTW you are not using power of Doubly linked list. There is no end pointer. It looks like you using singly linked list

Comment: I would assume this is for learning, it is rare to use a linked list in production code, even more so a custom one. And for learning you might as well check the [source for the built in linkedList](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/compmod/system/collections/generic/linkedlist.cs)

Comment: Ok, now this is _too much_ code, and we don't know what buttons you may be clicking during debugging, anyways, to manipulate `seatList`. (I do see that you have a `Form2.seatList` field — which is only accessed by serialization code and what appears to be a `Reset` button — and a `Form2._seatManager` field, which itself contains its own `DoubleLinkedList`.) Can you just post some [minimal code that reproduces your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by instantiating a `DoubleLinkedList()` and immediately calling its methods until it reaches the desired state?

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just write

```
public void deleteAllNodes()
{
    this.Start = null;
}
```

and let the garbage collector clean up the mess.